# I'm trying to get user Id and put it in txt file from which role has in one server. discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so, as I said, I'm trying to get user Id from specific role which has the member, and put it inside a txt file, this is the code that I did:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        premium = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)

        if premium.id == "945200418181480459":
            with open('miao.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(f"{str(user_id)}\n")
                f.close()
```

but don't work, no error, nothing.
any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have fix, I think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Bonnie! Where have you defined `user_id`? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah, is that!!